# Dúvida sobre como preencher array de duas dimensões em Java

Tags: java, array, algoritmo, array-multidimensional

Estou fazendo um exercício e preciso de ajuda. Esse é o enunciado:

> Calcule as médias das temperaturas de cada mês. Para isto, crie uma lista contendo os nomes de cada mês nas linhas, e da quantidade de dias de cada mês nas colunas. Em cada dia, armazene cada valor de temperatura escrito pelo usuário. Depois, faça a média das temperaturas de cada mês.

Aqui segue o código que eu já fiz, mas eu nem sei mesmo como fazer direito já que eu sou iniciante em Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MediaTemperaturas {

public static void main (String args[]) {

double mês = new double[12][31];

for (int i = 0; i<11; i++);

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

String nomesMeses = sc.nextLine();

for (int j = 0; j<30;j++);
```

Para não ficar muito grande esse teste, pode fazer com números menores, como por exemplo, 3 meses, sendo que cada mês contém 10 dias (aí nesse caso tem que escrever 30 valores (3 * 10), para se chegar ao resultado dos meses).
Pode fazer:

```
double mes = new double [3][10];

**//Pra calcular a média, faz um:**

 int soma = 0;

 int media = 0;

 if (int i = 0; i < dias.length; i++) {



   soma += dias;

   media = soma/dias.length;

   return media;

}
```

Minhas dúvidas:

- E como fica para escrever o nome de cada mês na linha?
- Como se faz para preencher os valores em cada coluna?

Por gentileza, alguém pode me ajudar a fazer este Algoritmo?

Ah, há mais uma restrição: Não posso usar o `get`, o `set`, o `throw` e o `this`, pois o que estou fazendo é bem básico e de nível bem iniciante.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá. Primeiro:

```
String[] meses = {
    "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",  "Maio", "Junho",
    "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"
};

// Vamos dizer que fevereiro tem 29 dias porque este ano é bissexto.
int[] diasNoMes = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

Segundo, você pode percorrer os dias da seguinte forma:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
    String nomeMes = meses[i];
    for (int j = 1; j <= diasNoMes[i]; j++) {
        System.out.print("Digite a temperatura do dia " + j + " de " + nomeMes + ":");
        temperaturas[i][j - 1] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Aquele `j - 1` ao invés de apenas `j` é porque os dias começam em 1, mas o array começa em 0.

E se as suas temperaturas são `double`, então a sua `soma` também tem que ser `double` e a `media` também tem que ser `double`.

Espero que isso te ajude e que você consiga desenvolver o seu algoritmo.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado.
Uma dúvida, por favor:
Na frase:
"for (int j = 1; j <= diasNoMes[i]; j++) {"
Não deveria ser:
for (int j = 0; j<= diasnoMes[i]; j++) {

Já que o j vai começar na primeira posição que é o zero?

Comment: @InicianteemJava A razão de `j` começar em 1 é para que o texto `"Digite a temperatura do dia " + j .....` não fique `"Digite a temperatura do dia 0"...` Note que depois, quando o `j` é usado para indexar o array é-lhe somado 1: `temperaturas[i][j - 1] = sc.nextDouble();`. Talvez seja mais intuitivo começar em zero e somar 1 no texto: `for (int j = 0;....` `System.out.print("Digite a temperatura do dia " + (j + 1) ....` `temperaturas[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();`

Comment: Como ficaria o método: 
public static double[] calcularArrays (double[] mes) { 
int soma = 0;
int media = 0;
String meses [] = {"Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março"}; int diasNoMes = {5,5,5}; 
for (int i = 0; i<meses.length;i++) { 
String nomeMes = meses[i]; 
for (int j = 1; j<=diasNoMes[i]; j++) { 
System.out.println("Digite a temperatura do dia "+j+" de " +nomeMes + ":"); 
temperaturas[i][j-1] = sc.nextDouble();
soma += temperaturas [j];
media = soma/diasNoMes.length;
return media[i];
} 
} 
} 
}

Está certo? Como ficaria para corrigir e executar o código perfeitamente?

Comment: @InicianteemJava Qual é a sua dúvida? Ele está a dar erro?

Comment: Sim, continua a dar erro.
Podes testar o seu código aí, e depois colocar aqui quando estiver executando?

Comment: @InicianteemJava Entenda que o *stackoverflow* não funciona assim. Seja especifico na sua dúvida. Se dá erro diga qual. Eu julgo que deve ser por causa do *array* `temperaturas` não ter sido declarado. No inicio coloque a seguinte linha: `double temperaturas[12][31];`. Note que o código postado na resposta apenas serve para pedir ao utilizador que indique as temperaturas em cada dia do mês.

Comment: @InicianteemJava **CORRECÇÃO:** No inicio coloque a seguinte linha: `double[][] temperaturas = new double[12][31];`